# If or query, if criteria is met, copy from other sheet

Tags: google-sheets, match, vlookup, google-forms, google-query-language

I think, what I am trying to do is pretty simply. But I cant seem to get it right.

I have 2 taps In one sheet.

`Sheet 1` is an Overview of `Sheet 2.`

In `Sheet 1` I have in column `A` the status for each pallet. In Sheet 2, I have the overview of the content of each pallet.

Now I just want to select once, the status (if Sold or Available) in Sheet 1 and it now automatically copies the status to `Sheet 2`, where the criteria of the pallet name is met.

EG: `P-0011`  is marked as **sold** in `Sheet 1` - In `Sheet 2` all rows who contain `P-0011` will automatically copy the status to the cell.

I have tried

```
=if('Recap Pallets'!C:C,B2,'Recap Pallets'!A:A)
```

But it's not working.

I have also tried

```
=query('Recap Pallets'!A:C,"Select A where A='Sold' or A='Available'")
```

but also this seems wrong, because it just copies the row, and not the content regarding to the matching criteria.

What is the mistake?

Please see here example:

[SHEET](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1o6nLpyjTHFboE1-WxDjzI1uxF5FHzcbZ09ttuZAr2ro/edit#gid=1411883419)

Comment: Could you also include the expected output in your sheet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

delete everything in A column and use this in A1:

```
={"Status"; INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(B2:B, {'Recap Pallets'!C:C, 'Recap Pallets'!A:A}, 2, 0)))}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick and dirty solution:

```
=iferror(INDEX('Pallets Total'!A:A,MATCH(C3,'Pallets Total'!B:B,0)),"")
```

There's certainly more elegant ways, but this may work for the time being.